# Constant Pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments

I have a two functions.

```
int person_exist( Person *const p1, const char name[]){
     //some code
}
```

now I have another function calling person_exist

```
int add_person(Person *const p1, const char name[]){
    // some code
    if(int person_exist(???,???) == 1){
    //do this
    }
}
```

so I am having trouble passing in p1 and name into person_exist.
Any Ideas?

Comment: The `int` before the call is wrong. Using `p1` and `name` should be okay with that fixed.

Comment: How do you call `add_person`? Considering it take the *exact* same arguments, I would say `person_exist` should be called the same way.

Answer (score 0):

My idea:

```
int person_exist( Person *const p1, const char name[]){
     //some code
}

int add_person(Person *const p1, const char name[]){
    // some code
    if(person_exist(p1,name) == 1){
    //do this
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain!